# corian sink overflow tube and box replacement

Tags: plumbing

Does anyone sell the plastic box for the overflow tube on a Corian sink. I can find the tube for sale but not the box.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking about. Pictures would help a lot.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is one source](https://www.boatoutfitters.com/replacement-overflow-tube-for-corian-sinks) for the box and tube.  Your sink model number should be molded into the underside of the bowl.

Comment: That seems to be a nice find. Please disclose your affiliation with the web site, just to be sure...

Comment: Regardless, it's a nice answer.